# how to perform a non blocking get

Tags: webdriver, protractor

If a user has a valid session my landing page redirects the user to the restricted page. eg. if a user accesses the www. subdomain he gets redirected to the user. subdomain.

The problem I ran into when testing this is that when I perform a browser.get("www.."), webdriver seems to wait for the page to load, which never happens because of the redirect. Then webdriver seems to notice that the url is not the url it needs to go to and changes it again and so the browser is hopping back and forth between the two domains until the timout is reached.

Is there a way to prevent webdriver from waiting for the page to be loaded when performing a get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Turn the synchronization off*:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```